# Computation of Riemann zeta's derivative on the critical line

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, riemann-zeta

For the zeta function itself, I have been using the Riemann-Siegel Z formula implementation as written here: https://web.viu.ca/pughg/thesis.d/masters.thesis.pdf

However, my searching skills have completely failed me on the derivative. Is there an algorithm that calculates the derivative that is relatively easy to understand, and/or doesn't involve too much computation?

Comment: Which part of the paper are you referring to?

Comment: @IraeVid Section 3.2 has the aforementioned formula. There's also a C implementation: https://web.viu.ca/pughg/thesis.d/zetaHalfPlusIt.c

Comment: A fairly simple formula that I believe converges fairly rapidly on the critical line is $$\zeta'(s)=\underset{K\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{(1-s)\, (2 K+s-1) \log (K)-2 K}{2\, (s-1)^2\, K^s}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K-1} \frac{\log (k)}{k^s}\right),\quad\Re(s)>-1$$ which was derived from $$\zeta(s)=\underset{K\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{2 K+s-1}{2\, (s-1)\, K^s}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K-1} \frac{1}{k^s}\right),\quad\Re(s)>-1.$$